# Debugging openlayers 5 application, using source map

Tags: google-chrome, openlayers, source-maps, openlayers-5

I am migrating from openlayers 2 to 5. I have downloaded [distribution](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/download/v5.2.0/v5.2.0-dist.zip) with minified js and source maps. Then I included js file in index.html:

```
<script src="bower_components/openlayers/ol.js"></script>
```

Now I want to debug sources. When I am step into `ol.js` there is 'Source Map detected' message. The problem is I don`t see in chrome dev console sources from source map file:

[image]

Comment: what happens if you click on "more" next to "Source Map detected"?

Comment: @geocodezip I see following https://i.imgur.com/8aF8xxT.png, but if I press `Ctrl + P` - don't see openlayers sources. I type `proj.js` or other file name from github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I am using ol-debug.js for debugging. Perhaps source map is better way to debug, but still can`t make it work. I have followed https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8330. It works only on linux/mac. So to compile ol-debug.js(npm should be installed):

```
git clone https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers.git
cd openlayers
npm install
npm install --global rollup
```

Then follow steps in github issue.